A challenging problem in Geometry related to finding a reciprocal relationship between AM,AB and AC

Let A be a point exterior to a circle l. Two lines through A meet the circle l at points B and C, respectively at D and E (with D between A and E). The parallel through D to BC meets the circle l for the second time at F. The line AF meets l again at G and the lines BC and EG meet at M. Prove that
$$\frac{1}{AM} = \frac{1}{AB}+\frac{1}{AC}$$
My Attempts

I tried to solve this question with a number of approaches, I first considered the relationships between the various points and lines. Since A is exterior to the circle and the lines intersect the circle at B, C, D, and E, I tried to explore how the parallel line (DF) interacts with the circle.
Recognizing that DF is parallel to BC, I thought this might create similar triangles or some proportional relationships, but I couldn’t find a straightforward way to link this to the harmonic properties or cross-ratios.
Next, I tried to use properties of cyclic quadrilaterals since B, C, E, and G are involved in multiple cyclic figures. The fact that AF intersects the circle again at G and that lines BC and EG meet at M seemed like it could lead to some useful geometric properties or ratios, but the exact way to piece this together wasn't clear to me.
I also considered if there might be some application of the power of a point theorem here, particularly since we have several intersecting lines and a circle. This seemed promising, but I couldn’t find a way to directly connect this to the equation $\frac{1}{AM} = \frac{1}{AB} + \frac{1}{AC}$.
Despite trying, I was unable to solve the problem please someone guide me on how to connect AM,AB and AC so that we can prove the relationship between them

I would highly recommend adding a diagram to this question - it would really help...

Ok I am generating the image

Thanks. Helps a lot. Nice problem, where is it from?

I also don't know exactly where this problem comes from but in the worksheet which I was solving it was written RO 2006 under the question, now I don't know what that means.

@RedFive This is from Romanian Mathematical Competition 2006 – RMC 2006 – Bucharest 2006. See here, Page 14-15, Problem 10. The solution is given at the top of Page 73.

$\angle MAG= \angle GFD= \angle MED$
$\implies \triangle MAG \sim \triangle MEA$
$\implies AM^2= MG \cdot ME= MB \cdot MC= (AB-AM)\cdot (AC-AM)$
$\implies \dfrac {1}{AM}= \dfrac {1}{AB}+ \dfrac {1}{AC} $

(+1) short and sweet

@RandomGuy Thank you.
